# Recommended graphic software for creating great graphics in game?

Tags: 2d, 3d, game-design, graphics, blender

I came across a game called Trine2. It has a great graphics here is one image i captured [here](http://postimg.org/image/ui5o85wy5/). Forgive me but I need 10 reputation to upload image so i use external sites.

How did they create that game? Its  a 2d side scrolling game with 3d graphics? what applications they used? Is it Photoshop or illustrator then some 3d modeling software like blender? Or they only use a single graphic software? Theres also some shadow in character but i believe its OPENGL or Directx. Im more concern on how did they create such grapchis in 2d with 3d looks.

Comment: Actually, Trine is a 3D game. It just uses the 2.5D concept, to enrich the graphics. Gameplay is constrained to X, Y axes. Trine 2 is actually mentioned [right here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D#3D_games_with_a_two-dimensional_playing_field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer to your question: I'm not sure what they used for this specific game, but I'm 99% sure it was 3ds max or Maya for the 3D models, Photoshop for the textures, and their game engine's level editor for laying out the scenes.

Beyond that direct answer: Ultimately software doesn't matter that much for the quality of the graphics. I mean, the reason I'm pretty sure about my guess is because those are the applications used for the majority of games, but even though most games use the same standard tools they vary a lot in graphics quality. It's about the artist making the art, not the software.